# iFrames do not open full page as instructed in code

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

I have a website designed ages ago that uses iFrames.  www.ussvanguard.info.  The site opens fine in an editor (full screen; height 100%; width 100%) but in current versions of chrome, firefox and IE the iframe is not expanding and the content can't be read.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a new Internet Explorer window, pull down the Tools menu, and select Internet options:
   [image]

enable IFRAMES

2. The Internet options dialog will launch:
   [image]
3. Click the Security tab, select the Internet icon, and then click the Custom Level button:
   [image]
4. Scroll down to the Launching programs and files in an IFRAME section.  Click the Prompt (recommended) radio button if you want Internet Explorer to notify you when an IFRAME is encountered, or click the Enable (not secure) radio button to allow IFRAMES to load without any notification.

[image]

5. Save your edit and close all open dialogs by clicking the OK buttons.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your website contains coding errors. Fix these first.

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ussvanguard.info%2F:

```
12 Errors, 4 warning(s)
```

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css21&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ussvanguard.info%2F:

```
Errors (7)
```